# How many permutation matrices are their own transpose?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations, permutation-matrices

I want to know, for any $n$, how many  $n \times n$ permutation matrices are their own transpose/inverse. For example, for n=3, the matrix below is it's own inverse; when multiplied by itself, you get the identity.
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
This could also be described as being symetrical over the diagonal.
For $n=3$, 4 out of the 6 possible matrices have this property. For $n=4$, 10 out of the 24 have it, if I'm not mistaken. For $n=4$, the matrices that work can be put into three 'categories':

1. The identity matrix
2. Matrices that switch two elements from the identity, like the below, in which the first and second rows are switched:
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
   (There are  4 choose 2 of these, choosing the two to switch.)
3. Matrices that switch two pairs of two elements from the identity, like the below, which switches rows 1+3 and 2+4:
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   (There are $2 \choose 4$$/2$) ways of doing this; similar to the above, dividing by 2 for double counting.)

$1+6+3=10$ possible $4 \times 4$ matrices.
Anyway, it'd be great to know if there's a good way to find this number for any given value of n. For any number after 4, there are a lot more possibilities to consider.

Comment: Permutations who are self-inverse are specifically those permutations whose cyclic-decomposition contains only cycles of length $2$ (*or cycles of length $1$ if you choose to include those as well*)

Comment: These are called involutions. Their [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A000085) gives the formula $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{n!}{(n-2k)!2^kk!}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!